# VBA Subscript out of Range Error appearing after Collection contains so many elements

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, collections

I'm really struggling to find what's generating the 'Subscript Out Of Range' error in my code below.  What I'm trying to do with said code is to read data from text files having a time stamp within 90 days of the current date.  To collect this data, I'm reading each file line by line, storing that data into a split array, then populating two collections with specific rows of the split array.  This code works fine with another application of it that I'm using to retrieve data only from a specific job set. The code in the aforementioned application appears to be working fine until I reach one particular file which doesn't differ in any way (formatting, content, or otherwise) from previous files that were successfully read.  It seems to me that I'm reaching the size limit of each collection but I'm not sure.  Below is my code:

```
Private Sub Analyze_90Day_Data_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Data_Selection_21075A.Hide
    'Declare Variables
    Dim FFFile As String
    Dim SplitData() As String
    Dim DateIter As Long
    Dim CurrentDate As Date
    Dim FileDate As Date
    Dim colSN As String
    Dim colSet As String
    Dim KPCDate As Date
    Dim CMMArray() As Variant
    'Remove old data from 21075A KPC
    LastRow = Sheets("21075A KPC").Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row
    For SheetRow = 12 To LastRow
        Sheets("21075A KPC").Range("G" & SheetRow & ":H" & SheetRow).ClearContents
    Next SheetRow
    'Populate 21075A KPC with new data
    CurrentDate = Date
    KPCDate = DateAdd("d", -90, CurrentDate)
    CMMArray = Array("Inspcmm1", "Inspcmm2")
    For CMM = LBound(CMMArray) To UBound(CMMArray)
        With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
            CMMFolder = "\\" & CMMArray(CMM) & "\cmm\21075A\OP290"
            On Error GoTo ResumeIter
            Set CMMFold = .GetFolder(CMMFolder)
            For Each SetFolder In CMMFold.SubFolders
                FFFile = SetFolder & "\21075A-030-FINALFLOWTOT " &     SetFolder.Name & ".txt"
                MsgBox SetFolder.Name
                FileDate = FileDateTime(FFFile)
                If FileDate >= KPCDate Then
                    LineIter = 0
                    With .OpenTextFile(FFFile, ForReading)
                        Do Until .AtEndOfStream
                            LineIter = LineIter + 1
                            LineData = .ReadLine
                            SplitData = Split(LineData)
                            'Extracting Serial Number
                            strSN.Add SplitData(0)
                            'Extracting Final Flow Value
                            strFF.Add SplitData(2)
                        Loop
                        .Close
                    End With
                End If
            Next SetFolder
        End With
ResumeIter:
    Next CMM
    If strSN.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Neither Brown & Sharpe is online."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        SheetRow = 12
        For SNIter = 1 To strSN.Count Step 1
            With Sheets("21075A KPC")
                .Range("G" & SheetRow).Value = strSN.Item(SNIter)
                .Range("H" & SheetRow).Value = strFF.Item(SNIter)
            End With
            SheetRow = SheetRow + 1
        Next SNIter
        LastRow = Sheets("21075A KPC").Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row
        With Sheets("21075A KPC")
            'Calculate & Populate Means
            .Range("H5") = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Range("H12:H" & LastRow))
            'Calculate & Populate Standard Deviations
            .Range("H6") = WorksheetFunction.StDev(.Range("H12:H" & LastRow))
            'Populate 90-Day Reporting Period
            .Range("F3") = KPCDate
            .Range("F4") = CurrentDate
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

All variables not declared in the above procedure have already been publicly declared.  Thanks for looking into this.  Please let me know if you need anything else from me.

Comment: Please annotate or otherwise disclose what code line the error is being produced on. No one can actually run your code without many things that were omitted but we might have a chance at determining what the problem is if you tell us where it occurs.

Comment: It may be that they array SplitData doesn't have anything in position 2 for the line and file that are breaking.

Comment: @Jeeped, the line of code on which the error occurs is 'strSN.Add SplitData(0)'.  If I comment out this line, the error jumps to the next line 'strFF.Add SplitData(2)'.

Comment: Hi, please see my comment above regarding which line is giving me the error..  I could really use some help determining why after so many files the code stops working when there isn't anything inherently wrong with the files from which I'm trying to read data.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the SplitData array wasn't getting emptied and was consequently reaching its size limit, causing the Subscript Out of Range Error.  I added the code line 'Erase SplitData()' after the code line 'Do Until .AtEndOfStream' and this emptied the SplitData array each time to prevent the accumulation of unnecessary data.